# I want a custom dialogue with close button

Tags: android

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT9po.png)I have done the coding but issue is that when i open dialog,close button show only half. It only shows the portion of close button inside of relative layout.
Outside part has not been shown. I am trying from hours but still not get the solution. So if any one has idea then please help me.
Thanks in advance. ! 
Below is my code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="385dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Choose From Gallary"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Camera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Take a Picture"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send_Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_notification_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />    
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Choose From Gallary"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Camera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Take a Picture"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send_Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_notification_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Some sort of explanation for why this is supposed to solve the problem would be good.

Comment: @Michael Yeah I should have explained. Here it goes:

Comment: @DeepPatel As it's LinearLayout, it should be wrap_content for both layout_width & layout_height in this case. And you used '-10dp' for both layout_marginRight and layout_marginTop which took your cancel button out of dialog layout (I hope, You know this point)

Comment: @mustafiz012 ok bro.. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Choose From Gallary"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Camera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Take a Picture"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send_Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_notification_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_From_Gallary"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @NileshRathod Hey there, I came across your profile and I would like to know why you linked **the best person on earth** to my profile? It is truly a great compliment :D